# How to use floating-whatsapp in React App?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, whatsapp

**floating-whatsapp Link:-**

https://github.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp

I want to use this in my react app. Because in react we can not use jquery easily. So How to use it?

Comment: Install jquery using `npm` or `yarn` instead of `CDN`.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal so we should not use cdn link in index.html file? and if yes then what I should have to install exactly instead of it?

Comment: I have added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**To install Jquery without CDN use:**

NPM:

```
npm install jquery
```

Yarn:

```
yarn add jquery
```

Bower:

```
bower install jquery
```

Use the one which you are using to install ReactJS.

> Official Documentation: https://jquery.com/download/#downloading-jquery-using-npm-or-yarn

Comment: after installation how to use this https://github.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp ? It give errors?

Comment: @yuvraj I have never used it, so I am not aware of it. It seems not so popular too.

Comment: @yuvraj can I know what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure, I want to have whatsapp floating icon where I over the mouse it popups same as in the given which I sent you. So this whatsapp icon want to achieve in my react app at the bottom right side.

Comment: So you want to make a chat app with WhatsApp theme. Or you are making something for a client or personal interest.

Comment: no no, please see https://github.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp once, so I just want the same just to put in my website, that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227145/discussion-between-yuvraj-and-manas-khandelwal).